# XML content into PHP variables

Tags: php, arrays, xml, variables

I have been at this for hours now and really can't get it working... I have the following content in an xml file:

```
<stores data="4850" times="01010101">
  <folder info="storage" DateTime="datetime1" update="212121012" versionNumber="ver1" url="http://url1" locater="location1"/>
  <folder info="images" DateTime="datetime2" update="1421748774" versionNumber="ver2" url="http://url2" locater="location2"/>
</stores data>
```

And I need to get each element into a different variable using PHP. This is the code that I have, which gets the xml file and prints it out, but after this I'm stuck.

```
$xml_ip = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
print_r($xml_ip);
```

With this I get what looks like an array on the screen, but I can't get all of the xml entries into variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid XML, if you make the XML valid it will work

So change the file to

```
<stores data="4850" times="01010101">
  <folder info="storage" DateTime="datetime1" update="212121012" versionNumber="ver1" url="http://url1" locater="location1"/>
  <folder info="images" DateTime="datetime2" update="1421748774" versionNumber="ver2" url="http://url2" locater="location2"/>
</stores>
```

All I did was fix this line

```
</stores data>
```

**Copy/Paste will get you every time!!!**

Then you will get this :-

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [data] => 4850
            [times] => 01010101
        )
    [folder] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [info] => storage
                            [DateTime] => datetime1
                            [update] => 212121012
                            [versionNumber] => ver1
                            [url] => http://url1
                            [locater] => location1
                        )
                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [info] => images
                            [DateTime] => datetime2
                            [update] => 1421748774
                            [versionNumber] => ver2
                            [url] => http://url2
                            [locater] => location2
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**Reply to additional comment**

You already have this data in a variable, this line

```
$xml_ip = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
```

creates a PHP SimpleXMLElement object called `$xml_ip`

You now need to learn how to deal with this object, [here is the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

And here is a simple bit of code to print out data as a head start.

```
$xml_ip = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

echo $xml_ip->attributes()['data'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $xml_ip->attributes()['times'] . PHP_EOL;

foreach ( $xml_ip->folder as $xmlEltObj ) {

    foreach ($xmlEltObj->attributes() as $attr => $val) {
        echo '   '. $attr . " = " . $val.PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Which prints

```
4850
01010101
   info = storage
   DateTime = datetime1
   update = 212121012
   versionNumber = ver1
   url = http://url1
   locater = location1
   info = images
   DateTime = datetime2
   update = 1421748774
   versionNumber = ver2
   url = http://url2
   locater = location2
```

Comment: Hi thank you, sorry, my bad, I was copying and got that part wrong. I do indeed get this output, how do I put each element into a variable?

Comment: See addition info on the bottom of the answer

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting there...

echo $xml_ip->attributes()['data'] . PHP_EOL;  is what I was looking for.

But how do I get each of the additional outputs from the foreach into a separate variable?

Comment: Why bother, address them from within the class structure. Why create everyting twice

Comment: I wish I understood that, you've lost me, thank you for your help and taking the time to explain. I just need to get each item into a variable. the first two in the individual lines work, but once it goes into the foreach, i can't get them into an individual variable.